# What is the 4-way SIMD version of float selection on OSX Accelerate framework?

Tags: macos, llvm, sse, simd, intrinsics

Using the [Accelerate framework](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Performance/Conceptual/vecLib/Reference/reference.html) from OSX, you get access to 4-way SIMD functionality where you can operate on vector floats, vector ints and vector bools. It gives you 4-way divisions e.g. and also 4-way sin,cos,tan etc.

For a vector float of 4 floats, the framework provides **vFloat**.
For a vector bool of 4 bools, the framework provides **vBool32**.

What I am trying to accomplish is the 4-way SIMD version of this line of code:

```
  float a = ...;
  float b = ...;
  bool  condition = ...;

  float selected = condition ? a : b;
```

On a Cell processor e.g., you would use the intrinsic 'spu_sel(val1, val2, conditional)'.

I tried writing down the 4-way selection as:

```
vFloat a = { ... };
vFloat b = { ... };
vBool32 condition = { ... };

vFloat selected = condition ? a : b;
```

...which is not accepted by the LLVM compiler, as the '?' operator does not accept vBool32.
Also, there is no operator called 'vsel' or 'vself' or something similar on the webpage mentioned above. Is there floating point selection available at all in this framework? And if so, how to access it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to work at this level of abstraction then you'll probably have to settle for multiplying by 1.0f or 0.0f to achieve the desired result. This is actually still quite efficient because AltiVec and SSE can both issue at least one SIMD floating point multiply per clock cycle.

If you want to get every last bit of performance though then I think you'll need to drop down to native SIMD programming and use the relevant intrinsics (`vec_sel` in the case of AltiVec, `_mm_blend_ps` in the case of SSE4, `_mm_and_ps`/`_mm_andnot_ps`/`_mm_or_ps` in the case of older SSE implementations).